Applying a patch on an Availability group instance
Looking at the Microsoft documentation for applying a SQL patch on an AG.
reference is made to reducing/minimizing downtime and data loss and not avoiding downtime totally. Can I expect to be able to apply a patch without any downtime at all?
I'd appreciate your thoughts please.
Thank you

It is there in the article :   ".. You can reduce downtime for the primary replica to only a single manual failover by performing a rolling upgrade (or two manual failovers if failing back to the original primary)... Downtime after the initial failover will depend on the number of databases in the AG. "
So, you can get zero downtime if a "patch" doesn't restart  SQL or OS.

@AndreySamykin thanks too for your time.


Can I expect to be able to apply a patch without any downtime at all?

This is impossible for us to say given you didn't define "downtime". In the general sense of the word for things that most people would attribute to downtime then the answer is no, there will be downtime. A failover will kill connections to the listener of the AG and the client will need to attempt the connection (depending on client library used and version, transparent reconnection may be possible) and thus the user may experience a disruption or "downtime".
If you have some corporate speak version of downtime, then it may be possible to have "no downtime" according to your definition.
Having said this, it is entirely possible to patch in the middle of the day with no one knowing. It requires a knowledgeable operations person (DBA, etc.) with the client applications being properly written. In a previous life as a DBA I patched multiple servers during the day without a single incident being created, YMMV based on apps and experience with the database systems.

thank you so much, that is very helpful. Much appreciated.
